# How to sort the name along with age in java

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I am new to Java 8. I just want to sort by the name. But the condition is: if there are duplicate names then it should be sorted according to age.

For example my input is

```
tarun  28
arun   29
varun  12
arun   22
```

and the output should be

```
arun   22
arun   29
tarun  28
varun  12
```

But I get something like

```
varun  12
arun   22
tarun  28
arun   29
```

Means it's sorted either only by ages or names.

This is the code which is implemented:

POJO class:

```
class Person {

    String fname;

    int age;

    public Person() {
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public Person(String fname,  int age) {
        this.fname = fname;

        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return fname  + age;
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.add(new Person("tarun", 28));
        persons.add(new Person("arun", 29));
        persons.add(new Person("varun", 12));
        persons.add(new Person("arun", 22));

        Collections.sort(persons, new Comparator<Person>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Person t, Person t1) {
                return t.getAge() - t1.getAge();
            }
        });
        System.out.println(persons);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Currently you are a) only comparing by one attribute and b) not really making use of Java 8's new features.

With Java 8 you can use [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) and chained comparators, like this:

```
Collections.sort(persons, Comparator.comparing(Person::getFname)
    .thenComparingInt(Person::getAge));
```

This will compare two `Person` instances first by their `fname` and - if that is equal - by their `age` (with a slight optimization to [`thenComparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) to avoid boxing).

Answer (score 4):

You need to compare for names first. 
If the names are the same, then and only then the result depends on comparing the age

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    persons.add(new Person("tarun", 28));
    persons.add(new Person("arun", 29));
    persons.add(new Person("varun", 12));
    persons.add(new Person("arun", 22));

    Collections.sort(persons, new Comparator<Person>() {

        public int compare(Person t, Person t1) {
            int comp = t.getFname().compareTo(t1.getFname());
            if (comp != 0) {    // names are different
                return comp;
            }
            return t.getAge() - t1.getAge();
        }
    });
    System.out.println(persons);

}}
```

if you want to change from ascending to descending, just change the sign. e.g.

```
 return -comp;
```

or swap the person

name

```
 int comp = t1.getFname().compareTo(t.getFname());
```

age

```
 return t1.getAge() - t.getAge();
```

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right path, but your `compare` method is incomplete.

Since `compare` is called to decide which item in each pair is to go before the other, it must include all comparison logic, not only the tie-breaking one. Your code sorts on the age alone, ignoring the name completely.

The logic should go like this:

- Compare names using `t.getFname().compareTo(t1.getFname())`
- If names are *not* the same, return the result of comparison
- Otherwise, return the result of comparing ages.

Proper way of comparing integers is with the static [`Integer.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)) method, i.e. `Integer.compare(t.getAge(), t1.getAge())`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Comparator` is only sorting by age, not by name.

You could try it like that:

```
new Comparator<Person>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person t, Person t1) {
        int ret = t.getFname().compareTo(t1.getFname());
        if (ret == 0) {
           ret = Integer.compare(t.getAge(), t1.getAge()); 
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

You could also think about implementing `Comparable<Person>` in the `Person` class itself:

```
class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person p) {
        int ret = fname.compareTo(p.fname);
        if (ret == 0) {
           ret = Integer.compare(age, p.getAge()); 
        }
        return ret;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Comparator.comparing`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-comparator-comparing) method, introduced in Java 8, returns a Comparator object that will use the specified field as the sort key.

```
final Function<Person, Integer> byAge = person -> person.getAge();   
final Function<Person, String> byTheirName = person -> person.getFname();
System.out.println("Sorted in ascending order by age and name: ");
        List<Person> sortedlist =   people.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(byAge).thenComparing(byTheirName))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        sortedlist.forEach(System.out::println);
```

We first created **two lambda expressions**, one to return the age of a given person and the other to return that person’s name. We then combined these two **lambda expressions** in the call to the `sorted()` method to compare on both properties. The `comparing()` method created and returned a Comparator to compare based on age. On the returned Comparator we invoked the `thenComparing()` method to create a composite `comparator` that compares based on both age and name

Answer (score 0):

This is simple **one liner** comparison using ternary operator for sorting the objects. **No need to write so many if/else block**.

```
Collections.sort(persons, new Comparator<Person>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Person t1, Person t2) {

        return t1.getFname().equals(t2.getFname()) ? t1.getAge()-t2.getAge() : t1.getFname().compareTo(t2.getFname());

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

// Sort Without using Comparator

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SortByNameThenAge {

```
static class Student {
    String name;
    int age;

    public Student(String name, int age) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Student> olist = new ArrayList<>();
    olist.add(new Student("Sam", 26));
    olist.add(new Student("Sam", 22));
    olist.add(new Student("Abc", 25));
    olist.add(new Student("Abc", 22));
    olist.add(new Student("Abc", 23));
    olist.add(new Student("Sam", 24));
    olist.add(new Student("Sam2", 21));
    olist.add(new Student("Sam2", 19));
    // Order By name
    for (int i = 0; i < olist.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = olist.size() - 1; j > i; j--) {
            if (olist.get(i).name.compareTo(olist.get(j).name) > 0) {
                Student temp = olist.get(i);
                olist.set(i, olist.get(j));
                olist.set(j, temp);
            }
        }
    }

    for (Student s : olist) {
        System.out.println(s.name + " : " + s.age);
    }

    // Order by name then age
    for (int i = 0; i < olist.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < olist.size(); j++) {
            if (olist.get(i).name.compareTo(olist.get(j).name) == 0) {
                if (olist.get(i).age > olist.get(i + 1).age) {
                    Student temp = olist.get(i);
                    olist.set(i, olist.get(i + 1));
                    olist.set(i + 1, temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\nSorting by age keeping name as it is");

    for (Student s : olist) {
        System.out.println(s.name + " : " + s.age);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the stream sorted method with static reference of getName and getAge methods.

```
List<Person> list=new ArrayList<Person>();
list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getName).thenComparing(Person::getAge)).collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: @user:10852356/garmia garg How a List of Person object can be used in comparing method? There will be a compilation error, 
either write Person::getName & Person::getAge instead of Employee::getName & Employee::getAge or 
create a List <Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>(); 

The correct use would be : 
List<Person> list=new ArrayList<Person>();
list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getName).thenComparing(Person::getAge)).collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(System.out::println);